# What is the difference between Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH and Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH in Java's Calendar class?

Tags: java, calendar

Java's Calendar class provides for two fields: WEEK_OF_MONTH  and DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH. Can someone explain the difference to me? It seems that they both return the same value when tested using the code below:

```
Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
date.set(2011,5,29);
int weekNo1 = date.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH);
int weekNo2 = date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH);
```

Comment: The docs explain this quite well. http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#WEEK_OF_MONTH

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Week of Month is the week within the current month starting from sundays how many weeks have there been.

Day of week of month is the day 5 would be Thursday,  1 sunday ect.

Comment: `WEEK_OF_MONTH` depends on the first day of week. No all calendars have Sunday has beginning of the week. France for example, has Monday as first day of the week.

Comment: This answer is completely incorrect. `DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH` is "the number of times the weekday has occurred during the month", as @user3096406 mentions below.

Answer (score 37):

- **`Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH`** simply returns **"Current week number in current month"**
- **`Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK`** simply returns **"Current day number in current week starting on last Sunday"**
- **`Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH`** returns **"N if current day is Nth day of month"** say **"3 if today is 3rd Wednesday in month"**

So I am writing this on 21st December 2016:

[image]

And this is what I am getting:

```
Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
System.out.println(today.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));          //outputs 4, as today is 4th day in this week which started on 18
System.out.println(today.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH)); //outputs 3, as today is "3rd Wednesday of this month". Earlier two wednesday were on 7th and 14th
System.out.println(today.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH));        //outputs 4, as currently 4th week of a month is running
```

Comment: Awesome explanation

Comment: This answer gets my vote for providing a visual example.

Answer (score 21):

The difference is that DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH provides the number of times the weekday has occurred during the month and WEEK_OF_MONTH just returns the week number within the current month.  Think of it this way, if the month starts on a Wednesday, the first Monday will occur during the second week of the month.  The value for DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH for that Monday would be 1, but the WEEK_OF_MONTH would be 2.

Answer (score 9):

I found all of the other docs confusing, so for any Microsoft developers like myself this one might be clear for you, as it was for me:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa986432(v=vs.80).aspx

> A constant representing a value for how many times a given day has
>   occurred in the month.

Comment: For Unix developers the Sun/Oracle docs on this topics are also quite confusing ;-)

Comment: "how many times a given day has occurred in the month." explained everything. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You must also take in count that Calendar.getInstance depends on Locale. So, you sometimes could have to specify a concrete Locale instead of the default Locale, for instance: Calendar.getInstance(new Locale("es","PE").

For the example, avobe, Calendar.getInstance(new Locale("es","PE") the calendar will consider first days of the week the Mondays, in other Locales could be other days

Comment: Nope, not correct for [`Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html#DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH) specifically. To quote the JavaDoc: “Unlike WEEK_OF_MONTH and WEEK_OF_YEAR, this field's value does not depend on getFirstDayOfWeek() or getMinimalDaysInFirstWeek(). DAY_OF_MONTH 1 through 7 always correspond to DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH 1; 8 through 14 correspond to DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH 2, and so on.”

Comment: Basil Bourque, I never refer to Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH, I just noticed that Calendar is dependent on Locale

Comment: But this Question *is* about `Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH`.

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

- <s>`Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH`</s>

  - Obsolete, never use `Calendar`.
  - Means the nth week within a month, with definition varying by `Locale` and the result of [`getFirstDayOfWeek()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html#getFirstDayOfWeek()).
  - If you want to define a week as week-of-month # 1 is the week containing day-of-month 1, then use: `LocalDate::get( ChronoField.ALIGNED_WEEK_OF_MONTH )`
- <s>`Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH`</s>

  - Obsolete, never use `Calendar`.
  - Means the nth day-of-week within that month, such 2nd Tuesday, where weeks are defined as week # 1 containing day 1 of that month.
  - Replaced by `LocalDate::get( ChronoField.ALIGNED_DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH )`

## Avoid `Calendar` legacy class

Be aware that the `Calendar` class used in the question is terrible, and was supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310). Do not use `Calendar` nor `GregorianCalendar`. They were designed by people who did not understand date-time handling.

## java.time

### `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) or [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset).

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2020 , Month.JANUARY , 23 ) ;  // 2020-01-23.
```

### Convert

If given a `Calendar` object that is really a `GregorianCalendar`, you can easily convert to a modern `ZonedDateTime` object.

```
GregorianCalendar gc = ( GregorianCalendar ) myCalendar ;  // Cast from more general class to the concrete class underlying.
ZonedDateTime zdt = gc.toZonedDateTime() ;
```

Extract the date-only portion.

```
LocalDate ld = zdt.toLocalDate() ;  // Extract the date, omitting the time-of-day and the context of a time zone.
```

### `ChronoField`

You can interrogate a `LocalDate` object via the `get` method with various [`ChronoField`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/temporal/ChronoField.html#ALIGNED_DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH) enum objects.

> [`Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html#WEEK_OF_MONTH)

This asks for the week of the month. But how do you define a week of the month? Unfortunately, the `Calendar` class’ definition varies by `Locale`. So your results may vary at runtime.

If your definition is that week # 1 has the first day of the calendar month, you can interrogate a `LocalDate` using [`ChronoField.ALIGNED_WEEK_OF_MONTH`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/temporal/ChronoField.html#ALIGNED_WEEK_OF_MONTH).

```
int weekOfMonth = ld.get( ChronoField.ALIGNED_WEEK_OF_MONTH ) ;
```

> [`Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html#DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH)

This means the nth day-of-week found in the month, such as 2nd-Tuesday or third-Thursday. Unlike `Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH`, this definition does *not* vary by `Locale`. Week # 1 is the week containing day-of-month 1. This legacy `Calendar` class really is an awful mess, confusing and inconsistent. Good riddance.

Now in *java.time*, use instead [`ChronoField.ALIGNED_DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/temporal/ChronoField.html#ALIGNED_DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH).

```
DayOfWeek dow = ld.getDayOfMonth() ;  // Get enum object representing day of week such as `DayOfWeek.MONDAY`. 
int nthDayOfWeekOfMonth = ld.get( ChronoField.ALIGNED_DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH ) ;
```